# SwiftUI drag and drop multiple rows in the same List View

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm trying to replicate the drag and drop behavior that Apple's Reminders app does; drag, select, and drop multiple rows in one drag

I figured this would work with `.onMove(performAction:)` since the source param is a set of indexes vs just one but no luck!

Here's a demo of the code below on my iPhone (note, AFAIK, you can't do multi-touch to drag and drop on a simulator easily, or at all):
[demo](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1758210/178394978-369dc2a6-f3f3-4334-a2db-9c4fccfcb138.MP4)

Here's the behavior in the Reminders app:
[reminder's app](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1758210/178395136-5f227fcf-5d18-41f5-908d-ea38c2d552e9.MP4)

```
import SwiftUI
import UniformTypeIdentifiers

struct ContentView: View {
  @State private var rows = [
    "First",
    "Second",
    "Third",
    "Fourth",
  ]

  var body: some View {
    List {
      ForEach(rows) { row in
        RowCell(row: row)
          .onDrag {
            NSItemProvider(object: row as NSString)
          }
      }
      .onDelete(perform: deleteRows)
      .onMove(perform: moveRows)
      .onInsert(of: [UTType.text, UTType.url], perform: insertRows)
    }
  }

  private func deleteRows(offsets: IndexSet) {
    for offset in offsets {
      rows.remove(at: offset)
    }
  }

  private func moveRows(from source: IndexSet, to destination: Int) {
    rows.move(fromOffsets: source, toOffset: destination)
  }

  private func insertRows(at destination: Int, items: [NSItemProvider]) {

  }
}

struct RowCell: View {
  let row: String

  var body: some View {
    Text(row)
  }
}

// String+SwiftUI

extension String: Identifiable {
  public var id: String {
    self
  }
}
```

Thanks a billion!

Comment: ErickES7 Did you get the solution? moveRows method not getting called from .onMove.

Comment: @RahulGupta no luck. I'll have to dig into the API again. Maybe Apple added something  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @RahulGupta I'm not following; `.onMove` is passed the `moveRows` method vs called via a closure